# Passing variable to be evaluated in groovy gstring

Tags: groovy, gstring

I am wondering if I can pass variable to be evaluated as String inside gstring evaluation.
simplest example will be some thing like

```
 def var ='person.lName'
 def value = "${var}"
 println(value)
```

I am looking to get output the value of lastName in the person instance. As a last resort I can use reflection, but wondering there should be some thing simpler in groovy, that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try:

```
 def var = Eval.me( 'new Date()' )
```

In place of the first line in your example.

The [Eval class is documented here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html)

**edit**

I am guessing (from your updated question) that you have a person variable, and then people are passing in a String like `person.lName` , and you want to return the `lName` property of that class?

Can you try something like this using GroovyShell?

```
// Assuming we have a Person class
class Person {
  String fName
  String lName
}

// And a variable 'person' stored in the binding of the script
person = new Person( fName:'tim', lName:'yates' )

// And given a command string to execute
def commandString = 'person.lName'

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell( binding )
def result = shell.evaluate( commandString )
```

Or this, using direct string parsing and property access

```
// Assuming we have a Person class
class Person {
  String fName
  String lName
}

// And a variable 'person' stored in the binding of the script
person = new Person( fName:'tim', lName:'yates' )

// And given a command string to execute
def commandString = 'person.lName'

// Split the command string into a list based on '.', and inject starting with null
def result = commandString.split( /\./ ).inject( null ) { curr, prop ->
  // if curr is null, then return the property from the binding
  // Otherwise try to get the given property from the curr object
  curr?."$prop" ?: binding[ prop ]
}
```

Comment: My bad I should have been little more specific, what I am trying to do is to pass the class instance and value of attribute dynamically. Some thing like 
obj.fName
if I do 
var value = "${obj.fName}" evaluation is fine but if I do some thing like
String str = "obj.fName" and I want to resolve value of fName at runtime. Reason being what attribute and object I will get at runtime is unknown

Comment: Can you edit your question to put in an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Amit had another guess at what you are trying to do...  I assume you have a 'person' object somewhere?  Anyway, I hope I have shown you two possible methods

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried the 2nd one and works exactly the way I wanted it to. Thanks a lot and appreciated your response.