# Use variable to access config in Grails Holders

Tags: grails, groovy

Using Grails 2.3.7, I set a property in my config file:

```
foo.bar = ['whatever']
```

I can access using `Holders`...

```
Holders.config.foo.bar
```

For convenience I put `Holders` in util method:

```
static getCfgProp(key){
  Holders.config.get(key)
}
```

But `getCfgProp('foo.bar')` doesn't work (guessing because `foo.bar` is nested map key).

It works if I flatten the config:

```
static getCfgProp(key){
  Holders.getFlatConfig().get(key)
}
```

..but don't want to do that each time method is invoked.

Tried these, none worked, I must be missing something simple

```
Holders.config."${key}"
Holders.config."$key"
Holders.config.getProperty(key)
Holders.config.(key)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9180039/6509

Comment: @tim_yates, what's your take: go with `Eval` or flatten config, in terms of performance?

Comment: Always avoid eval if possible

Comment: can you elaborate why, tim?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've used for displaying a config var value (via a form input):

```
grailsApplication.config.flatten()."${it}"
```

where `${it}` is the input string. This works for both non-nested and nested keys due to the `flatten()` method.

EDIT: just realised this is the equivilent of your `Holders.getFlatConfig()` so probably not useful. Not sure why you

> don't want to do that each time method is invoked

Performance? Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: I have not bench-marked it, but tim said to not use Eval, so little choice left! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me with grails-2.5.6:

```
Holders.config[key].subkey.subsubkey...
Holders.config[key][subkey].subsubkey...

// for Holders.config.foo.bar.zet
Holders.config['foo'].bar.zet
Holders.config['foo']['bar'].zet
Holders.config['foo']['bar']['zet']
```